# JAVA installer runs and says it's installed but JAVA does not appear in programs and does not run

Tags: windows-10, installation, 64-bit, java

My pc is a genuine Windows 10 64-bit system.

I'm currently trying to install JAVA 14 because a program I want to run requires that specific version. However, I've also tried installing the newest version of JAVA before and the same problem persists.

I installed via an exe. file from Oracle Archives. The installer runs and displays java has been successfully installed but upon entering `java -version` in cmd, this text is displayed: `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` And as I said in the title, Java is not listed in my add/remove programs. The only thing the installer seems to do for me is to add a java file in program files (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2) and nothing else.

I've also tried running the installer as administrator, disabling UAC and windows security and reinstalling as administrator, and also installing manually via the zip file, all to no avail (I couldn't find the described path file, in environmental variables, to edit in the manual install). Also tried JavaRa, and the program could not find any Java versions.

Also tried Jarfix as both user and administrator, does nothing.

Comment: After the java installer closes, do you find the java folder in C:\Program Files\Java?

Comment: Restart the command prompt and retype `java -version`, the current instance of command prompt may not be aware of the new java path

Comment: @CodeTiger 1. Yes the folder was there, but I couldn't find it in add/remove programs and JavaRa says it isn't installed although the installer itself says the installation was successful.

2. I've done that multiple times, doesn't change the fact that Java wasn't actually installed and isn't working.

Comment: Is there a bin folder in the Java jdk and jre folders?

Comment: @CodeTiger There's only a jdk folder but yes, there's a bin in there.

Comment: Java will never work without a jre

Comment: https://imgur.com/NLLjXtf

Comment: Whenever your running java, the java virtual machine is invoked which starts the java runtime environment, install the runtime environment and it should be good to go

Comment: @CodeTiger What version of Java is that? The 14 installer only got me the jdk file. I remember reading somewhere that versions higher than 11 no longer have two separate versions/can no longer choose which one to install?

Comment: Add the path manually to your environment variables then

Comment: This official documentation from Oracle should help you
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwju76qslfjwAhUE9IUKHStYAd4QFjABegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fessential%2Fenvironment%2Fpaths.html&usg=AOvVaw2juGDr5c1HCx3ysjNrUd1X

Comment: @CodeTiger Do you know whether I'm supposed to link it to a particular application/application extension in the bin or just the bin?

Comment: Ah nvm nvm I added a path to the bin in system variables and it worked. A tutorial I looked at before wrongly told me to add it to the user one. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out a tutorial I followed before to try installing from a zip file wrongly instructed to edit path in user variables after adding a new variable named JAVA_HOME, instead of the system one. So it didn't work. I merely had to add a new path to the system and adding a new variable wasn't neccesary to get it to work.